# Как установить ос с флешки?

Tags: bios, ос

Версия Биоса GGCN20WW. В интернете не могу найти ничего. Биос какой-то странный, не такой как в интернете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый что ни на есть обыкновенный BIOS от Lenovo.

Чтобы мне не описывать то, чего в интернете и так предостаточно, просто оставлю Вам [ссылку](https://www.google.com/search?q=bios%20GGCN20WW&source=lmns&bih=649&biw=1366&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj0wYmWr6bzAhUL8hoKHe8dBvwQ_AUoAHoECAEQAA).